# Resteasy 3.0.23 version not working for InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

Tags: file-upload, resteasy

Resteasy 3.0.10 was working fine for 
InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);

But when we upgraded resteasy to 3.0.23, now this code this throwing below exception.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$PartImpl.getBody(MultipartInputImpl.java:335)

Any help or hint will be very helpful.

Regards
Anju Singh

Answer (score 1):

This line 335 is:

```
MessageBodyReader<T> reader = workers.
    getMessageBodyReader(type, genericType, empty, contentType);
```

Probably your `workers` is null. The workers is injected by:

```
protected @Context
Providers workers;
```

This NullPointerException problem could happen if your application override the implementation of `createPropertyInjector` method in a class extending `InjectorFactoryImpl`.

For instance, this could be configured via web.xml, overriding the resteasy injector factory:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.injector.factory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myapplication.resteasy.config.MyClassThatExtendsInjectorFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you override this method and forget to call the `super.createPropertyInjector` in some point, the `@Context` injection will not occur and this null pointer problem happens.